# stack overflow exception in thread on Android

Tags: android, stack-overflow

I am doing code for calculating bpm for media files. my requirement is i have to play song only for 5 seconds not more than 5 seconds. so i use Thread.sleep(5000) and i call handler message. it throws java.long.stackoverflowexception.

my code:

```
currentThread.start(); 
....    
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.e("bpm", "in run method");
            BPM2SampleProcessor processor = new BPM2SampleProcessor();
            processor.setSampleSize(1024);
            EnergyOutputAudioDevice output = new EnergyOutputAudioDevice(processor);     
            output.setAverageLength(1024);      
            try {
                player = new Player(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/taxi.mp3"), output); // line no 40
                currentThread.run();  // line no 41
                player.play();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           text.setText("bpm is  "+processor.getBPM());
           Log.e("bpm","  bpm is  "+processor.getBPM());            
           Thread.sleep(5000);
       threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                         Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() 
{
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
    {
     Log.e("calledThread","5seconds");  
     player.close();
    }
};
```

log cat:

```
  05-20 18:05:01.761: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
  05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777): java.lang.StackOverflowError
  05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:49)
  05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:45)
  05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer.<init>(ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer.java:49)
  05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.BufferFactory.newByteBuffer(BufferFactory.java:51)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:54)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:351)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.nio.charset.Charset.encode(Charset.java:711)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:1022)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.Util.getBytes(Util.java:61)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.io.File.properPath(File.java:1362)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:77)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at beatit.beatit.main2.run(main2.java:40)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at  beatit.beatit.main2.run(main2.java:41)
 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

 05-20 18:05:02.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.la
 05-20 18:05:05.573: ERROR/JavaBinder(1276): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost answered yourself:

```
currentThread.run();  // line no 41
```

Below I wrote example how to deal with your problem:

```
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //put your code here
        }
    };

    try {
        task.execute((Void)null).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: after i remove `currentThread.run();` the song is continuously playing. not stop after 5 seconds. what to do for stop? please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Your thread calling the run method over and over again, causing a stackoverflow:

```
currentThread.run();
```

There is no condition to stop that. (Just to make it clear, `currentThread.start()` calls the run method in some stage)

Comment: you better do. why is it there in first place?

Comment: after i remove `currentThread.run();` the song is continuously playing. not stop after 5 seconds. what to do for stop? please help me.

Comment: add a sleep for another 1 second after you send the message to the handler. It should work, unfortunately I don't have an android around me to test it now.

Comment: Thread.sleep(5000);
 threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
 Thread.sleep(1000);
i did above coding. but i get following error: please help me
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: it's hard to tell exactly what you should do without more code, but any GUI operation should be performed on the GUI (main) thread. look at AsyncTask, it might help you --> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i have used only one text view i edit my question which has what you told before. i ignored only declaration and other functionality. other parts does not affect this part.

Comment: Please don't edit the question in a way that makes it a new one. If you have another question (and you do), please ask it as a separate one. but in short - you need to call this line: `text.setText("bpm is  "+processor.getBPM());` from UI thread.

Comment: UI thread? how to call it? i am new to android. so i get struggle.

Comment: @murali_ma: Just use AsyncTask as I wrote you.

Comment: actually i am struggling with AsyncTask.

Comment: You could use `publishProgress()` method for that (read AsyncTask docs before)